# Two forms - two submit buttons. How the controller identify which button was clicked?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two forms with two submit buttons in one page, one view and one controller should manage them. I want it to perform one action if the first one is clicked, and another action - if the second. I tried this where edit is the name of the form but it doesn't work:

```
if($this->getRequest()->get('edit'))
```

I also tried setting value to the submit buttons but I could't make it go, too. Please help me to find a way how to identify which button was pressed. :)

Comment: If you have two forms, they should submit to two different scripts.  Your submit buttons will exist inside their respective forms, and therefore you'll know which was pressed by the script that it submitted to.

Comment: From some excellent arguments today to a stupid comment. Shame on you Matt. Why cant two forms submit to one script. e.g. Add, Amend Delete record

Comment: @Matt there can be more `submit` buttons in one `form` tag. @Faery: Try to use `print_r` or `var_dump` on `$_POST` to check what is submitted (name of the clicked submit button is sended with it).

Comment: @Matt very lame example.

Comment: @Sven there *can* be cloned dinosaurs running around Isla Nublar, but that doesn't mean there *should* be? :-P

Comment: In fact the one button updates the data in one table and the other adds data to another table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give buttons different "name" (not "id") attributes

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="submit" name="btnA" value="ActionA">
<input type="submit" name="btnB" value="ActionB">
</form>
```

Then the controller should analyze the POST data for a variable whose name will be the name of the clicked button:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnA'])) { 
    /* do A */ 
} else if (isset($_POST['btnB'])) { 
   /* do B */ 
}
```

Comment: I think that their names are different.

Comment: If so, check the $_POST data. BTW, have you specified the input type = `submit`?

Comment: I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine and Twig and I don't know exactly what syntaxis to use with the request object.

Comment: I'm sorry...No idea about Symfony2.. Anyway, I think I misunderstood the question, since I am assuming each form has 2 buttons... Is it right? Or is there a button in each form?

Comment: There is one button for each form - the fisrt form is used for update of one table and the button is "Save", while the other is used for adding data to another table and its button is "Add"

Comment: I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: This site is for helping, isn't it? :-) Well, in such case, then, the solution I posted is still valid (assuming you are posting to the same script) because the isset() function will check what button has been clicked to submit the form.

Comment: Guys, anybody knows about Symfony?

Comment: @Claudix To get submitted data from request, simply do: `$request->get('your_value', null);`. Second argument - is return value in case if `your_value` in `$_REQUEST` array does not exist

Comment: So, $_REQUEST should contain the name of the clicked button, shouldn't it? In such case, @Faery could try to dump to a log file the contents of $_REQUEST to see what data is defined in it.

Answer (score 13):

Symfony 2.3 comes with the solution. It supports buttons in forms, and you have isClicked() method to check if a button was clicked.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms

Comment: Great symfony2 compliant answer, I didn't know about this method

Comment: `$form->get('delete')->isClicked()` is a new feature as of Symfony 2.3. But beware that if the button doesn't exist, and you use this method you will get an error. That seems obvious, but in many cases you may include a button conditionally, e.g. a delete button will only appear on editing an existing record, not creating a new one. So you should first check that the button exists, e.g. `if($form->has('delete') && $form->get('delete')->isClicked()) {`

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden fields and check their values :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller create two forms, handle their input and then check if they are submitted and valid.

```
$formOne = $this->formFactory->create();
$formTwo = $this->formFactory->create();

$formOne->handleRequest($request);
$formTwo->handleRequest($request);

if($formOne->isSubmitted() && $formOne->isValid()) {
    die('form one submitted');
}
if($formTwo->isSubmitted() && $formTwo->isValid()) {
    die('form two submitted');
}

return new Response($this->templating->render([template-name]), [
    'formOne' => $formOne->createView(),
    'formTwo' => $formTwo->createView(),
]));
```

Then inside your template create two forms with separate buttons:

```
form_start(formOne)
form_rest(formOne)
    <button type="submit">one</button>
form_end(formOne)


form_start(formOne)
form_rest(formOne)
    <button type="submit">one</button>
form_end(formOne)
```